# How can I change my Asus Eee Pad's language from Taiwanese to English?

Tags: asus-eee-pad-transformer, languages

I bought a Asus Eee Pad and when I did a factory reset the language was in Taiwanese.

How do I change it back to English? It looks like it only has Taiwanese on it.

I called Asus and they couldn't help me as they said that it had been converted into English by a Jail Broken Flash. I have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 2):

Use the icons.

First look for the settings app or icon (looks like cog wheels). Scroll through the list of apps in your launcher. You can also press the menu button while on your main homescreen and choose the settings from there (same idea - look for the cog-wheel icon).

Once you're in settings, look for the menu option with a little 'A' icon on the side - that's the one for Language settings. Press that.

Now press the very FIRST menu option to get a list of languages.

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> button. It will change it back. That's what I did.